skepticism about method of solving proper fraction
my professor used an unusual way to expand fraction for a fraction F (x)
$ F =    \frac{x^3 - x^2 + 1 }{(x^2+1)(x+1)^2}    =  \frac{\lambda_1}{(x+1)^2} + \frac{\lambda_2}{x+1} +  \frac{ax+b}{x^2+1}  $ .
the next step was multiplying F by the denominator of the first partial factor .
$ F * (x+1)^2 |_{x = -1} = \lambda_1 $
so multiplying the expanded version by $(x+1)^2$ wouldn't give $\lambda_1$ that's what i couldn't get my head around ,
$\lambda_1 = \frac{1}{2} =  f(1)* (x+1)^2 = \frac{-1 -1 + 1}{2}$
and then for the next step he did the same thing for $\lambda_2 \,, \lambda_3$ .
i didn't find any reference online of this way of solving partial fractions so i would like to know its name and the logic behind it, any help would be appreciated

It is called the "cover-up" rule (plenty of material online if you search) and will not get you $\lambda_2$ so easily (powers in the denominator are a little harder to handle), but multiplying through by $x^2+1$ and evaluating at $x=\pm i$ will get you $a$ and $b$.

Would you be more comfortable with $F = \frac{cx+d}{(x+1)^2}  + \frac{ax+b}{x^2 + 1}  ; ; ? ; ; $

One aspect of partial fractions is to reduce a rational function to a form that can be integrated. One reason why @WillJagy's suggestion is often further refined is to reduce to integrable components (substitute $y=x+1$ to see what is going on)

$\lambda_1=-\frac12$, not $+\frac12$. What "same thing" did he do for $\lambda_2$?
